# React activeClassName duplication

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm sorry. I'm not good at English.

I am developing with `React js`

I am using with `activeClassName()`, but I have a trouble.

I am trying to construct my website `URL` like that.

1. `localhost:3000/icons/`
2. `localhost:3000/icons/docs/`
3. `localhost:3000/icons/tutorial/`

and my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Header.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);


const Header = () => (
  <div className={cx('Header')}>
    <NavLink className={cx('title')} to="/icons">React Gotsu Icons</NavLink>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/icons" activeClassName={cx('active')}>Icons</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink activeClassName={cx('active')} to="/icons/docs">Docs</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink activeClassName={cx('active')} to="/icons/tutorial">Tutorial</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);


export default Header;
```

What I have trouble.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I want to make

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the function cx() do? Is it from a library? If i base myself on react router, I would say that this code doesnt detect exact urls. Meaning that your icon/ path will always return true when you’re under docs and tutorials as icons/ is part of these path. Make sure that cx() detects exact paths

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia I added my code. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /icons link is always active because every URL you use starts with /icons.

There's a property called `exact` that you can set for the /icons link. Then it will only be active if the URL is exactly "/icons" and not for "/icons/docs"

```
<NavLink exact to='/' className='title'>Home</NavLink>
```

[link with another example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4805)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's what I found. and I'm sorry. cause I questioned like poor.